# Is posible to use the method name with a wildcard with aop?

Tags: java, aop, spring-aop

I want to create a point cut using part of a method name and a wildcard, for example:

```
myMethodWrite()
```

So my idea is something like that:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* br.com.spring.aop.*myMethod*.*(..))")
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The [Spring AOP documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-examples) states

> The name pattern matches the method name. You can use the `*` wildcard
>   as all or part of a name pattern.

and gives an example

> the execution of any method with a name beginning with "set":
>
> ```
>  execution(* set*(..))
> ```